# while importing fusionexport-node-client in angular 6 , it is giving error

Tags: angular, export, angular6, fusioncharts

I have created an angular application and I using Fusion charts. Now I want to export fusion charts. I have configured fusion export server and client. I am adding lines related to fusion export in just app.module.ts and it is giving error. After commenting same, the application is running fine.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AgGridModule } from "ag-grid-angular/main";
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';
import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts/core';
import Column2D from 'fusioncharts/viz/column2d';
import mscolumn2d from 'fusioncharts/viz/mscolumn2d';
import FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/es/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';
import {ExportManager, ExportConfig } from 'fusionexport-node-client';
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, mscolumn2d, FusionTheme);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ExportManager,
    ExportConfig,
    FusionChartsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
    RouterModule.forRoot([ //localhost/path1/path2 localhost/path1
      {
        path:'',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path:'about',
        component: AboutComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The error is below. If I comment the import line from 'fusionexport-node-client' and  ExportManager, ExportConfig from import. It runs fine. 
1. What is the issue here?
2. Do I have to add all dependencies for fusionexport-node-client mentioned on page https://www.npmjs.com/package/fusionexport-node-client?
3. Does npm install command not install all dependent packages?

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js
186:21-40 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/parse5/lib/index.js
55:23-49 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/adm-zip/util/fileSystem.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'original-fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\adm-zip\util'

WARNING in ./node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\minimatch'

WARNING in ./node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\sax\lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\aws-sign2'
ERROR in ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\aws4'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\ecc-jsbn'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\aws4'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/oauth-sign/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\oauth-sign'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/request/lib/hawk.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/request/lib/oauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\tmp\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/verify.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\http-signature\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\http-signature\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/oauth-sign/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\oauth-sign'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/oauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/hawk.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/signature.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/dhe.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/certificate.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/fingerprint.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/identity.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/key.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/private-key.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/pem.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/ssh-private.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/openssh-cert.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib\formats'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/empty/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\empty'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/adm-zip/util/fileSystem.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\adm-zip\util'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\tmp\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/src/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/src/ExportConfig.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonfile/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\jsonfile'
ERROR in ./node_modules/pn/fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\pn'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\request\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\http-signature\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/util/utimes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\util'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/src/ExportConfig.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/file-api/Blob-impl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\file-api'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/navigator/NavigatorConcurrentHardware-impl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\navigator'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy-sync'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/empty/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\empty'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/ensure/link.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\ensure'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/ensure/symlink.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\ensure'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/ensure/file.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\ensure'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/ensure/symlink-paths.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\ensure'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\json'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json-sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\json'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/win32.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/mkdirs-sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/mkdirs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/move/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\move'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/move-sync/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\move-sync'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/output/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\output'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/util/utimes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\util'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/adm-zip/adm-zip.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\adm-zip'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/adm-zip/util/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\adm-zip\util'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/adm-zip/util/fattr.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\adm-zip\util'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/mime-types/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\mime-types'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\tmp\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/src/ExportManager.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/src/ExportConfig.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/src/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/common.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\jsdom\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\mime-types'
ERROR in ./node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\assert-plus'
ERROR in ./node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\combined-stream\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/legacy-streams.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/isstream/isstream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\isstream'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/ed-compat.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\sshpk\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/adm-zip/methods/deflater.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\adm-zip\methods'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/adm-zip/methods/inflater.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\adm-zip\methods'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fusionexport-node-client/node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\fusionexport-node-client\node_modules\request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Angular\testrouting\node_modules\request'
```

Comment: Looks like it is not supposed to be used in Angular. It's meant to be used as a NodeJS SDK.

Comment: is there any way we can use it in Angular?